# Asp.Net Core Ajax не правильно работают функция комментария

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

Итак! Есть простая задача сделать функцию, комментарии.
Сделал я это так:

**метод комментария:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Comment(int postId, string userId, string content, Comment comment)
        {
            var publ = _context.Publications.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == comment.PostId);
            if (publ != null) comment.ImageUrl = publ.ImageUrl;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
                var comm = new Comment
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    PostId = postId,
                    Content = content,
                    CommentDate = DateTime.Now
                };
                comm.UserId = user.Id;
                _context.Add(comm);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View();
        }
```

**ajax и Html:
комментарий:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a onclick="openCommentForm(@Model.Id)" style="cursor: pointer; color: darkslategray;">Оставить комментарий</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="postdiv-@Model.Id" style="display: none; color: darkslategray;">
            <textarea id="posttext-@Model.Id"></textarea> <br/>
            <input type="button" id="postComment" onclick="sendComment('@Model.Id', '@Model.UserId')" value="Отправить"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
<script>
    function openCommentForm(postId) {
        $('#postdiv-' + postId).show();
    }

    function sendComment(postId, userId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Comment", "Comments")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'postId': postId, 'userId': userId, 'content': $('#posttext-' + postId).val() },
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                        alert('Ваш комментарий ' + '(' + $('#posttext-' + postId).val() + ')' + ' добавлен!!!',
                            data)
                    },
                    500);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Ошибка во время отправки комментария', this);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**модель Publication:**

```
public class Publication
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Изображение")] public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Описание")] public string Description { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Нравиться!")] public int Like { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Подписка!")] public int Subscription { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Количество  комментариев")]
        public int ComentCount { get; set; }

        public List<Comment> CommentsList { get; set; }

    }
```

**модель Comment:**

```
public class Comment
    {
        [Key] public int CommentId { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public Publication Post { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Изображение")] public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

**так же вот метод Create который в CommentController**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CommentId,PostId,CommentDate")] Comment comment)
        {
            var publ = _context.Publications.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == comment.PostId);
            if (publ != null) comment.ImageUrl = publ.ImageUrl;


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(comment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(comment);
        }
```

**метод Details**

```
// GET: Comments/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id, PublicationVM model)
        {
            ViewBag.Comment = _context.Comments.Where(c => c.PostId == id);

            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var comment = await _context.Comments
                .Include(c => c.Post)
                .Include(c => c.User)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CommentId == id);
            if (comment == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(comment);
        }
```

Собственно вот в чём проблема.
При добавлении комментария через форму ajax он создаётся, добавляется, но в деталях не отображается картинка

добавляю её так

```
<td>
            <img src="~/@Model.ImageUrl" width="700" height="450"/>
        </td>
```

Метод для получения картинки такой

```
public class FileUploadService
    {
        public FileUploadService()
        {

        }
        public async void Upload(string path, string fileName, IFormFile file)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

но если создать комментарий с помощью метода Create то картинка отображается  но сам комментарий (Content) нет.

Через Ajax

[image: Через Ajax]

Через Create

[image: Через Create]

Почему так происходит?

Я уже два дня сижу не могу понять почему.
Проект учебный , я только учусь, прошу не судить строго за реализацию и построение связей. Это мой первый такой проект.

Да, забыл написать! Если скрипты поместить в секцию Scripts

```
@section Scripts{
}
```

То скрипты вообще перестают работать. Хотя, правильно вроде в секцию помещать скрипты.

Comment: Почему вы задаете 3 вопроса в одном? Как эти вопросы связаны между собой?

Comment: @ tym32167 Я думаю что они все работают так как работают по одной причине. Так как суть ajax функции все похож да и принцы у них схожий. И если решить одну проблему решаться все. Я хотел,  сделать три вопроса, но так как все эти методы и модели связаны, сделал всё в одном вопросе.

Comment: я поясню мысль. Вот у вас 3 вопроса в одном - это значит, что отвечающий должен за раз ответить на 3 вопроса, но при этом получить баллы только за один вопрос. То есть по сути, отвечающий, если верно ответит, то недополучит 30 баллов (так как получит 15 баллов за один ответ вместо 45 за 3 ответа). Смысл тратить своё время на такой вопрос?

Comment: если же вы считаете, что решив 1 вопрос решатся все 3, то и задавайте 1 вопрос, вместо 3. Ваша задача при написании вопроса - указать [минимум кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы отвечающие не читали ваши простыни, а читали только минимальный, но достаточный для воспроизведения\понимания код. То есть и с этой точки зрения ваш вопрос выглядит плохо - много лишней информации. Я только его проскроллил и понял, что читать его не буду, так как автор (вы) просто вывалили кучу кода, не утруждая себя поработать над заданием хорошего вопроса

Comment: @tym32167 Вот это понимаю развёрнутый ответ!!! Доступно и понятно! Особенно про балы! Не знал! Да, вы правы! Переделаю сейчас.

Comment: @tym32167 Оставил только один вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 Про простыни ! СУПЕР!!! Вроде оставил только то что касается вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил комментарии к вашему коду

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Comment(int postId, string userId, string content, Comment comment)
{
    var publ = _context.Publications.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == comment.PostId);
    // я бы тут ещё добавил проверку, что то типа 
    // if (publ == null) return NotFound();
    // потому что если публикации в БД нет, то и добавлять комментарий не к чему.

    // тут вы меняете модель, но эта модель не пишется в БД, 
    // для записи в БД вы создаете новый экзеемпляр комментария, 
    // то есть эта строчка бесполезная и вам не нужна
    // - удаляем эту строчку if (publ != null) comment.ImageUrl = publ.ImageUrl;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        // раз вы создаете новый экземпляр комментария, то вам надо перенести в него все данные из модели
        // то есть тут вам не хватает установки УРл картинки из модели в класс, который вы будете сохранять
        var comm = new Comment
        {
            UserId = userId,
            PostId = postId,
            Content = content,
            // ImageUrl = publ?.ImageUrl, - этой строчки тут не хватает
            CommentDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        comm.UserId = user.Id;
        _context.Add(comm);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }   
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Увы, но нет! Сделал как вы предложили, вообще не работает.

Comment: @EugeneTM покажите код и поясните, что значит "вообще не работает"

Comment: Код  как вы показали. 1. При добавлении `ImageUrl = publ?.ImageUrl,` `?.ImageUrl` он хочет заменить null. Он её подсвечивает серым, как недостижимый код. По идее путь к картинке добавляется в этой строчке `if (publ != null) comment.ImageUrl = publ.ImageUrl;` Если её убираешь, то при нажатии на кнопку отправить, реакции не какой нет. так же пробовал `ImageUrl = publ.ImageUrl` но тоже не работает.

Comment: @EugeneTM а как вы проверяете результат? Вы в БД смотрели, что добавилось?

Comment: Всё заработало!!! Убрал проверку на `if (publ == null) return NotFound();` Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @EugeneTM пожалуйста

Comment: Сразу забыл спросить! Не могли бы объяснить ? в данном контексте?

Comment: @EugeneTM `ImageUrl = publ?.ImageUr;l` эквивалентно `ImageUrl = (publ != null ? publ.ImageUrl : null);`

Comment: понятно спасибо!